# Angularjs Is there a cleaner more "angular" way to replace a transcluded class value in a directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is the only way i could figure out how to get a directive to pull out an attribute from its origin element, get a new value by hitting a service, and then adding that new service method return as a class in the directive template. i'm wondering if there is an alternative pattern that might be cleaner then this pattern that might use ng-class or possibly ng-transclude:

html:

```
<my-directive data-condition="{{hour.condition}}"></my-directive>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function (myService) {
    return {
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: true,
      template: '<i class="{{wiIconClass}}"></i>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function($scope, $elm, attrs){
        $scope.wiIconClass=myService.getValue(attrs.condition);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: There is no transclusion in this directive

Comment: this link helped a lot in my solution - https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function `myService.getValue` is synchronous, you could simply do:

```
<div ng-class="getClass(hour.condition)">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getClass = function(condition) {
  return myService.getValue(condition);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can directly put your service within your scope:

```
$scope.myService = myService;
```

So the HTML becomes

```
<div ng-class="myService.getValue(hour.condition)">
```

---

In both cases, you will need to inject your service into your controller:

```
myModule.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
  // this controller has access to myService
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Directives scope` parameter instead of using the `Directives Attribute values`. This is because when using the attributes you will need to setup a `$watch` to see when that value updates, with using `$scope` you get the benefit of the binding aspect.

As far as to respond to the best way, its hard to say without knowing your actual task. You can have Angular update the elements `css class` value in several different ways.

Here's a working Plunker with some small updates to your existing code.
http://plnkr.co/edit/W0SOiBEDE03MgostqemT?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.hour = {
            condition: 'good'
        };
    })
    .factory('myService', function() {
        var condValues = {
            good: 'good-class',
            bad: 'bad-class'
        };
        return {
            getValue: function(key) {
                return condValues[key];
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('myDirective', function(myService) {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                condition: '='
            },
            template: '<i class="{{myService.getValue(condition)}}"></i>',
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                scope.myService = myService;
            }
        };
    });
```